# Can't get my reCaptcha to work on my ColdFusion form

Tags: coldfusion, recaptcha

I signed up for reCaptcha, got my private/public keys, made my recaptcha.cfm and put the code in my form. The form renders perfectly when you go to the URL but it submits even when the person doesn't put anything in the captcha. This is the code for my recaptcha.cfm and I have the relevant code for the form page commented out in recaptcha.cfm under "Sample." Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="true">
<!---
    Use the reCAPTCHA API to verify human input.

    reCAPTCHA improves the process of digitizing books by sending words that
    cannot be read by computers to the Web in the form of CAPTCHAs for
    humans to decipher. More specifically, each word that cannot be read
    correctly by OCR is placed on an image and used as a CAPTCHA. This is
    possible because most OCR programs alert you when a word cannot be read
    correctly.

    You will need a key pair from http://recaptcha.net/api/getkey to use this tag.


    Sample
    --------------------------------

        <html>
        <body>

        <cfform>

            <cf_recaptcha
                privateKey="6LepjdQSAAAAAMspsO04gZUXltxddkiI0ZgSF02h"
                publicKey="6LepjdQSAAAAADoLvfvgkwacBAI_GbL-nTy2zvS6">

            <cfinput type="submit" name="submit">

        </cfform>

        <cfif isDefined("form.submit")>
            <cfoutput>recaptcha says #form.recaptcha#</cfoutput>
        </cfif>

        </body>
        </html>


--->

<cfscript>
    CHALLENGE_URL = "http://api.recaptcha.net";
    SSL_CHALLENGE_URL = "https://api-secure.recaptcha.net";
    VERIFY_URL = "http://api-verify.recaptcha.net/verify";
</cfscript>

<cfif not structKeyExists(attributes, "publicKey")>
    <cfthrow type="RECAPTCHA_ATTRIBUTE"
        message="recaptcha: required attribute 'publicKey' is missing">
</cfif>

<cfif not structKeyExists(attributes, "privateKey")>
    <cfthrow type="RECAPTCHA_ATTRIBUTE"
        message="recaptcha: required attribute 'privateKey' is missing">
</cfif>

<cftry>

    <cfparam name="attributes.action" default="render">

    <cfif not listContains("render,check", attributes.action)>
        <cfset sInvalidAttr="action not render|check">
        <cfthrow>
    </cfif>

    <cfset sInvalidAttr="ssl not true|false">
    <cfparam name="attributes.ssl" type="boolean" default="false">

    <cfparam name="attributes.theme" type="regex" pattern="(red|white|blackglass)" default="red">

    <cfif not listContains("red,white,blackglass", attributes.theme)>
        <cfset sInvalidAttr="theme not red|white|blackglass">
        <cfthrow>
    </cfif>

    <cfset sInvalidAttr="tabIndex not numeric">
    <cfparam name="attributes.tabIndex" type="numeric" default="0">

<cfcatch type="any">
    <cfthrow type="RECAPTCHA_ATTRIBUTE"
        message="recaptcha: attribute #sInvalidAttr#">
</cfcatch>
</cftry>

<cfif isDefined("form.recaptcha_challenge_field") and isDefined("form.recaptcha_response_field")>

    <cftry>
        <cfhttp url="#VERIFY_URL#" method="post" timeout="5" throwonerror="true">
            <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="privatekey" value="#attributes.privateKey#">
            <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="remoteip" value="#cgi.REMOTE_ADDR#">
            <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="challenge" value="#form.recaptcha_challenge_field#">
            <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="response" value="#form.recaptcha_response_field#">
        </cfhttp>
    <cfcatch>
        <cfthrow  type="RECAPTCHA_NO_SERVICE"
            message="recaptcha: unable to contact recaptcha verification service on url '#VERIFY_URL#'">
    </cfcatch>
    </cftry>

    <cfset aResponse = listToArray(cfhttp.fileContent, chr(10))>
    <cfset form.recaptcha = aResponse[1]>
    <cfset structDelete(form, "recaptcha_challenge_field")>
    <cfset structDelete(form, "recaptcha_response_field")>

    <cfif aResponse[1] eq "false" and aResponse[2] neq "incorrect-captcha-sol">
        <cfthrow type="RECAPTCHA_VERIFICATION_FAILURE"
            message="recaptcha: the verification service responded with error '#aResponse[2]#'. See http://recaptcha.net/apidocs/captcha/ for error meanings.">
    </cfif>

<cfelse>

    <cfset form.recaptcha = false>

</cfif>

<cfif attributes.action eq "render">

    <cfif attributes.ssl>
        <cfset challengeURL = SSL_CHALLENGE_URL>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset challengeURL = CHALLENGE_URL>
    </cfif>

    <cfoutput>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        var RecaptchaOptions = {
           theme : '#attributes.theme#',
           tabindex : #attributes.tabIndex#
        };
    //-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
       src="#challengeURL#/challenge?k=#attributes.publicKey#">
    </script>
    <noscript>
       <iframe src="#challengeURL#/noscript?k=#attributes.publicKey#"
           height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
       <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
       </textarea>
       <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
           value="manual_challenge">
    </noscript>
    </cfoutput>

</cfif>

<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="false">
```

Answer (score 2):

That custom tag is badly out of date.  You need to update the URLs because Google changed them.  Change them to this:

```
CHALLENGE_URL = "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api";
SSL_CHALLENGE_URL = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api";
VERIFY_URL = "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify";
```

I have posted an updated version of this custom tag as a Gist here: https://gist.github.com/2210356